# How to configure Apache 2 to run a Python script from a Ruby CGI app with %x{}

Tags: python, ruby, apache, cgi, environment-variables

My Ruby CGI app is very simple, I would like to call a Python script, for example `youtube-dl`, or `youtube-upload` with `%x{youtube-dl --help}`

For the sake of simplicity, I would like to print only the help page of the `youtube-dl` Python script. So my Ruby script is also very simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "cgi"

cgi=CGI.new(:accept_charset => "UTF-8")

url=cgi['url']

puts "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\""
puts "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
puts

puts url
puts "-----------------------------------"
puts %x{youtube-dl --help 2>&1}
```

Then I can invoke this CGI app called `ytdl` with http://example.com/cgi-bin/ytdl?url=a_youtube_url. Unfortunately I get only a lot of error messages from the Python interpreter which is unable to import some packages, especially site-packages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import plistlib
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/plistlib.py", line 65, in <module>
    from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/xml/parsers/expat.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyexpat import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt
```

I think I would configure my Apache 2 web server to provide some environment variables for the Python interpereter, where it can find the packages. Unfortunately I have no experience with Python, I only learned Ruby till now. My Apache server runs CGI apps as user `daemon`, and when I login as `daemon` I can run the `youtube-dl` script without error messages.

Apache provide these environment for my CGI apps (printed with `puts %x{env}`):

```
UNIQUE_ID=VZN9RyX3N7MAAAs95zsAAAAI
RUBYOPT=rubygems
GEM_HOME=/home/XXXXXX/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
HTTP_USER_AGENT=Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16
HTTP_HOST=xx.xxx.xx.xxx
HTTP_ACCEPT=text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=en-US,en;q=0.9
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING=gzip, deflate
HTTP_CONNECTION=Keep-Alive
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/XXXXXX/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin:/home/XXXXXX/util
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lampp/lib:/opt/lampp/lib
SERVER_SIGNATURE=
SERVER_SOFTWARE=Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
SERVER_NAME=xx.xxx.xx.xxx
SERVER_ADDR=xx.xxx.xx.xxx
SERVER_PORT=80
REMOTE_ADDR=xx.x.xxx.xxx
DOCUMENT_ROOT=/opt/lampp/htdocs
REQUEST_SCHEME=http
CONTEXT_PREFIX=/cgi-bin/
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/opt/lampp/cgi-bin/
SERVER_ADMIN=you@example.com
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/opt/lampp/cgi-bin/ytdl
REMOTE_PORT=37798
GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD=GET
QUERY_STRING=
REQUEST_URI=/cgi-bin/ytdl
SCRIPT_NAME=/cgi-bin/ytdl
```

Meanwhile I realized that when I set the environment variable (either in Apache config httpd.conf with SetEnv directive, or with `ENV['PYTHONHOME']=value` in my Ruby script)
called PYTHONHOME to an empty string "" or "/usr/lib" , the error message disappers, and I get another one:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

When I set:

```
ENV['PYTHONHOME']="/usr/lib"
ENV['PYTHONPATH']="/usr/lib/python3.4"
```

I get another error message:

```
File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

So my question is, how should I configure my Apache 2 webserver to make Python scripts run and make them callable from other apps?

Answer (score 1):

When you run an application in a subshell you have to be aware of the environment being set up for that shell and application. The PATH and variables will be nonexistent or very limited which can affect its ability to find libraries.

Write a small CGI that outputs the Apache variables and environment passed to the script, either as a web page or to the log or a file and examine the results.

Also permissions and the user will be whatever the server sets up which is usually very restricted.

Also, seriously consider *not* using CGI. Instead use something more modern and flexible. Sinatra works nicely with Apache using something like Passenger to glue them together. Sinatra makes it really easy to do web-services, and actually works so well you can often do without a heavyweight server like Apache, especially during the development, test and early production stages. I have an API used in-house that handles a lot of enterprise-critical requests and it just cruises along.

Comment: Thx, I added the environment variable list. In fact it's nearly the same as I get when I am logged in with any user name.
I will try thos modern technologies too, but I am yet an absolute beginner, I would like to practise the processing of web forms with AJAX and CGI.